# How can I start and stop a loop within a jframe

Tags: java, swing, loops, jframe

I'm new to java
I have a requirement to output strings of data to an output port until I receive a string on the data port, then take other action.
Leaving aside the issue of com ports for the moment, I am trying to model the flow simply using buttons to start then stop the data, and am failing miserably.
This is the code I have created. I want to start output to the text area until I press the stop button.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class WriteToWindow extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private final static String newline = "\n";

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    WriteToWindow frame = new WriteToWindow();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public WriteToWindow() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        // try adding final
        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setRows(10);
        textArea.setBounds(27, 23, 377, 142);
        contentPane.add(textArea);

        JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
        btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // start writing to the text area
                int i = 1;
                textArea.append("You clicked start" + newline);
                do {
                    textArea.append("Iteration " + Integer.toString(i) + newline);  
                    i++;
                    // wait a second
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } while (true);// forever
            }
        });
        btnStart.setBounds(25, 188, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnStart);

        JButton btnStop = new JButton("Stop");
        btnStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //stop writing data to the text area
                textArea.append("You clicked stop" + newline);
                }
        });
        btnStop.setBounds(151, 188, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnStop);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach won't work as it blocks the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing it from processing any new events which may be raised, including `repaint` events.  This will essentially hang your program.

Instead, you need to off load the execution of the loop into some kind of background `Thread`.

While you can certainly use a `Thread`, you would become responsible for ensuring that you don't violate the single thread nature of Swing, that is, ensuring that any updates to the UI are performed within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

To this end I would recommend using a `SwingWorker`, as it allows you to do work in the background (separate `Thread`) while providing easy to use functionality to sync updates back to the EDT

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) in particular...